# nodejs exec ssh hangs

Tags: node.js, ssh

I want my nodejs app to execute a line of command and exit. The command is used for creating a remote port forwarding on a remote machine.

```
const exec = require("child_process").exec;

let script = "ssh -i cert.pem ubuntu@ec2 -R 9000:localhost:22 -S /tmp/.ssh-ec2 -M -fN ssh-ec2";

exec(script, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      console.debug(stdout);
});
```

> node test.js

It hangs there; but if I run pure command in terminal.

> ssh -i cert.pem ubuntu@ec2 -R 9000:localhost:22 -S /tmp/.ssh-ec2 -M -fN ssh-ec2

It exits.

What do I miss?

Comment: Hi @ahlev, did you fix this?

Comment: Same thing happening in one folder, while in other everything works OK with mostly the same one liner script (only difference is the target of rsync).
Also manually running the script works in both folders.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get working by passing `"ignore"` to `stdio` [config option provided by child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsstdio) like so:

```js
execSync(sshTunnelCommand, { stdio: 'ignore' });
```

Tried this based on the line from their docs reading:

> Use the { stdio: 'ignore' } option if the output will not be consumed